# How can I open an existing file in Xcode in C?

Tags: c, xcode, string, data-files

I have created a file called mahmoud.txt in the direceotry: `/Users/mahmoudhamra/Desktop/C language/`

I want to open it in Xcode.

I created the directory and the name of the file into a string each. 
Then I concatenated the file name to the directory and tried to open it to read it but it always gives me an error: "Thread 1: signal SIGBART".

Can someone help me please?
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


    FILE *inFile;
    char fileName[13];

    printf("enter file name: ");
    scanf("%s",fileName);

    char new[40]="/Users/mahmoudhamra/Desktop/C language/";
    strcat(new, fileName);

    inFile=fopen("new", "r");

    if (inFile== NULL) {
        printf("file %s was not opened!\n", fileName);
        printf("check that the file exists!\n");
        exit(1);


    }
    else
        printf("the files has successfully been opened!\n");




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I want to open it in Xcode".  Are you *sure* that's what you want to do?  Where is the stacktrace which will help us determine where the problem is?

Answer (score 3):

First of all this

```
char new[40]="/Users/mahmoudhamra/Desktop/C language/";
```

should be at least

```
char new[41]="/Users/mahmoudhamra/Desktop/C language/";
```

to leave space for null terminator. A C-string is an array of chars with a null-terminator (`0x00`, `'\0'`, `0`) as last char.

Best would be:

```
char new[]="/Users/mahmoudhamra/Desktop/C language/";
```

BTW your problem is that you have no space to add `filename` chars, so at least you should define it as

```
char path_and_file[128] = {0};
strncpy(path_and_file, "/Users/mahmoudhamra/Desktop/C language/", sizeof(path_and_file)-1);
```

If you want to learn something about dynamic allocation you can:

```
char *directory = "/Users/mahmoudhamra/Desktop/C language/";
char *path_and_file = malloc(strlen(directory)+1);
if (path_and_file != NULL)
{
   strcpy(path_and_file, directory);

   printf("enter file name: ");
   scanf("%s",fileName);

   path_and_file = realloc(path_and_file,strlen(directory)+strlen(filename)+1);
   if (path_and_file != NULL)
   {
      strcat(path_and_file, filename);

      // YOUR STUFF

   }
}


free(path_and_file);
```

Another way with dynamic allocation is using strdup to create your first string:

```
char *path_and_file = strdup("/Users/mahmoudhamra/Desktop/C language/");
```

**EDIT**

Last thing, as @visibleman pointed out, the call to `fopen` have to be changed to

```
inFile=fopen(new, "r");
```

or according to my examples:

```
inFile=fopen(path_and_file, "r");
```

Comment: This is a good answer. Additionally, I think the OP will want to remove the quotes around "new" in the fopen call.

Comment: That `strncpy()` call is broken as the copy length is the size of the destination buffer.  That cannot be right.

Comment: It's still broken.  What happens when the copy accesses memory in the source buffer that is beyond the size of the source buffer?  Undefined I would say.  Also WRT `malloc()` and `strcpy()`; have you heard of `strdup()`?

Comment: @trojanfoe 1st) I'm giving a solution for OP, not a solution for whatever. 128 chars are more than enough. 2nd) As I wrote: _If you want to learn something about dynamic allocation_. But, well, I add an example with `strdup`.

Comment: But the solution is unsound.  I am not convinced you understand the issue with `strncpy()`.

Comment: @trojanfoe Probably I need some coffee. Buffer is zeroed. So `strncpy` copy at most `sizeof(path_and_file)-1` bytes of literal C-string. So the last byte will be left unchanged: '\0'. After that, code has to take care about what happened with the `strncpy`: if it fails for length or there is no more space to add `filename` program must be killed... Am I wrong?

Comment: No actually you are right; apologies.  That is the correct use of `strncpy()`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is *almost certainly* the size of the `new` character array as it does not have the capacity to hold the complete filename and will cause a stack overflow:

```
char new[40]="/Users/mahmoudhamra/Desktop/C language/";
strcat(new, fileName);
```

Change the `40` to `1024`:

```
char new[1024] = ...;
```

Comment: @Lundin It's a reasonable size to accommodate any file path and is the size of the POSIX `PATH_MAX` on most systems.